# Python test mock some methods but not others

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, moto

How do I mock a certain part of a test and not another. I would like get an actually return for my url request, but use mock for a dynamodb part further on

```
import requests
from moto import mock_dynamodb
from requests import Session


@mock_dynamodb
def test_this():

    session = requests.Session()
    response = session.get(
        url,
        headers=headers,
        auth=auth)
```

But I'm getting a connection error (that I don't get if I don't mock)

> ConnectionError: Connection refused: GET
>
> ../../.virtualenvs/pw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/moto/packages/responses/responses.py:250:
>   ConnectionError

Comment: I think the problem here is not that you need to mock only in certain parts of tests, but rather that you should actually be splitting this test in two. One test where your db is mocked, and another where it is not.

Comment: @Eqomatic I tried that and still the request received a connection error     
    `def get_feed(url):

        session = requests.Session()
        response = session.get(
            url,
            headers=headers,
            auth=auth
        )

    return response

    @mock_dynamodb
    def test_this():

        response = get_feed(url)`

Comment: Have you considered mocking out `session.get()`?

Answer (score 0):

moto **catches all http requests not only those to endpoints of AWS**. I recommend you to mock the specific request by using [requests mock](https://github.com/openstack/requests-mock) or simply using mock library.